# How can I split the event file in S3 from Kinesis stream into small pieces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a collector is writing events to my S3 bucket then I need to use COPY command to load these data into AWS Redshift. These events are coming from SendGrid and about 11 topics, SendGrid provided 11 tables DDL. The events files are containing 11 topics in a single file, I need to separate them into 11 pieces depends on their content then execute the COPY command to achieve my goal.

Tried to use AWS lambda to create functions to do that, with limited Python skills, could not handle it.

I would not put all content of the event file there, [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMqwl.png) is the example. Each part in a pair of {} will need to be loaded into one table in redshift, their value of "event" will be the destination table.(processed, deferred and so on...)

Comment: Could you paste the content of the picture to your question as a code snippet?

Comment: xxx.xx.xx.xxx
�m���
UTF-8�ssc-0.15.0-kinesis,
Go-http-client/2.0@/com.sendgrid/v3Tr
[
{
  "email":"example@test.com",
  "timestamp":1570817837,
  "smtp-id":"\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e",
  "event":"processed",
  "category":"cat facts",
  "sg_event_id":"sxl-TBfWMuVnGNxg2hMQ3w==",
  "sg_message_id":"14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0"
}.....


And there are other 10 pairs of {}.